# onClick() not going to next Activity

Tags: android

I am trying to go to the next Activity of my app but onClick is unable to go to the next Activity. This is my code which I've tried so far. onClick plays the sound which I've just added. Before it was working fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton;
Animation performAnimation1;
ImageView androidImageView;
MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    performAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation1);
    performAnimation1.setRepeatCount(4);
    androidImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.androidImageView);
    androidImageView.startAnimation(performAnimation1);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
    imageButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    }

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}

}
```

**Mainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.learning_numbers"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="1"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.learning_numbers.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        android:name=".Numbers"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton imageButton;
Animation performAnimation1;
ImageView androidImageView;
MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
addListenerOnButton();
performAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.layout.animation1);
performAnimation1.setRepeatCount(4);
androidImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.androidImageView);
androidImageView.startAnimation(performAnimation1);

mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
imageButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mp.start();

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
}

}
```

Answer (score 11):

you override the `onClickListener` for `R.id.button1`. In your code you set two different `onClickListener` on the same button. And since is a `set` operation you will get only the last instance

Answer (score 1):

Remove `addListenerOnButton();` from your code and start activity in same lintner where you are calling `mp.start();` i.e.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either remove following code from oncreate

```
 imageButton = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

or else remove code from yours activity

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}
```

What you did is you overrided the onClickListener for R.id.button1 which is not proper.